# ¿Tiene nombre el lado opuesto del codo? ¿Cuál es?

Tags: sustantivos, cuerpo-humano

En estos días en que nos piden cubrirnos al estornudar con el antebrazo o con el codo, caigo en cuenta que  no nos cubrimos propiamente con el *codo*... nos cubrimos con la parte opuesta, si comparamos con el miembro inferior, lo que sería la *corva* respecto a la rodilla. ¿Tiene nombre esa parte del brazo? ¿Cuál es ese nombre?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo me quedaría con **sangradura**.

He visto distintas opciones como *pliegue del codo* ([referencia](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081126084445AApT8uX)), si bien [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fosa_del_codo) indica principalmente *fosa del codo*, dando como alternativas *fosa cubital*, *sangría* y *sangradura*. Estas dos últimas aparecen referenciadas en el DLE:

> [**sangría**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=sangr%C3%ADa)
>
> 3. f. Parte de la articulación del brazo opuesta al codo.

> [**sangradura**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=sangradura)
>
> 1. f. Parte hundida del brazo opuesta al codo.

Y esta última parece cubrir el concepto de forma más genérica.

Comment: Sé que no está cubierto en la pregunta, pero el nombre debe venir por ser la parte desde la cual suelen tomar las muestras de sangre...

Comment: Sí, tiene toda la pinta!

Answer (score 2):

Ayer en uno de los muchos videos que están publicando los sanitarios españoles mencionaron la palabra **flexura** para referirse a esa acción, **flexura del codo** más concretamente.

> [**flexura**](https://dle.rae.es/flexura) Del lat. flexūra.
>
> 1. f. Pliegue, curva, doblez.